# Unexpected value "MyModule" when i'm trying to add my own npm library to angular2 project

Tags: angular, npm, package

I've got my own library which include one module and one component.
After compile my library i add it to my main project by

```
npm link ng-shared
```

Then i try to add line in my module:

```
import { SharedModule} from 'ng2-shared';
```

and visual studio see it corectly, but when i try to add SharedModule to imports then i got the error:

```
Unexpected value 'SharedModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'
```

I'm trying to find the cause of this problem for long time now and i can't figure out anything.

Module code:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

import { FirstComponent } from "./first.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    exports: [
        FirstComponent
    ],
    declarations: [
        FirstComponent
    ]
})

export class SharedModule { }
```

Component code:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnChanges, ElementRef, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core"

@Component({
    selector: "com-copybox",
    template: `<h1>Hello</h1>`,
    host: {
        "(document:keydown)": "handleKeyboardEvents($event)",
        "(document:click)": "handleClick($event)"
    }
})

export class FirstComponent implements OnChanges {

    handleKeyboardEvents(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        if (event.code === "Enter")
            console.log("HELLO");
    }

    handleClick(event: any): void {
      console.log("CLICK");
    }
}
```

Then i compile this with webpack:

```
const helpers = require('./config/helpers'),
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    entry: helpers.root('index.ts'),

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('bundles'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'core.umd.js',
        library: 'ng-shared',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    externals: [/^\@angular\//, /^rxjs\//],

    module: {
        rules: [{
            enforce: 'pre',
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'tslint-loader',
            exclude: [helpers.root('node_modules')]
        }, {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            options: {
                declaration: false
            },
            exclude: [/\.spec\.ts$/]
        }]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            helpers.root('./src')
        ),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery',
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {
                tslintLoader: {
                    emitErrors: false,
                    failOnHint: false
                }
            }
        }),

        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['bundles'], {
            root: helpers.root(),
            verbose: false,
            dry: false
        })
    ]
};
```

or simple with tsc with tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true
  }
}
```

AppModule code:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from "@angular/core";
import { LoginService } from "../services/login.service";
import { PanelGuard } from "../guards/panel.guard";
import { AppComponent } from "../components/app.component";
import { SharedModule } from 'ng-shared';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        LoginService,
        PanelGuard
    ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you share `AppModule` code?

Comment: You can't add `@NgModule` to `declarations` array, only `imports` or `exports`

Comment: Can you share `AppModule` code

Comment: I was adding NgModule to imports array.

Comment: put `console.log(SharedModule);` front of @NgModule. What is the output?

Comment: Output from console.log: function SharedModule() {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple:
My project include node_modules and imported npm package also include node_modules folder.
There was a conflict, when i delete node_modules after npm link command from my npm package folder everything works great.

Thank you for your answers